# Binding select2 dropdown using asp.net c# javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net

Select dropdown is bind from SQL using asp.net SQL, when I'am going to select first value it's ain't able to select.

what can I do???

```
        var configParamsObj = {
            placeholder: 'Select an option...',
        };
        $("#ddlShowTicket").select2(configParamsObj);

        $("#ddlUsers").select2(configParamsObj);

    //********   Select2 /**********//
    $.fn.select2.defaults = $.extend($.fn.select2.defaults, {
        allowClear: true,
        closeOnSelect: true,
        placeholder: 'Select...',
        minimumResultsForSearch: 15 
    });
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this with C# and SQL if the only code you're showing us is javascript?

Comment: Is your full problem is in Javascript? Then tag Javascript. Else give more details of C# and SQL.

Comment: As it is a server side control, you need to use this selector for selecting the dropdown using jQuery : $('#<%=ddlUsers.ClientID%>') OR give a control a unique class name and try to find out with css class selector in jQuery : $(".ddlUsers")

Comment: $(function () {
                var ddlShowTicket = $("[id$='ddlShowTicket']");
                ddlShowTicket.select2();
                
                var ddlUsers = $("[id$='ddlUsers']");
                ddlUsers.select2();
            })

Comment: kindly ans here...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278719/selecting-value-in-select2-dropdown-using-asp-net-javascript